# inheriting from a class template with a default argument

Tags: c++, g++4.8

I've created a class looking something like this. The key is that it's got a main template argument plus a template base class with a default. There is also a templated copy constructor...

```
struct default_base{};

template <typename T, typename TBase=default_base>
class some_class : public TBase{
public:
    some_class(){}
    template <typename U, typename UBase>
    some_class(const some_class<U,UBase>& u){
        T t(U());
    }
};


int main(){
    some_class<int> a;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this annoyingly vague compiler error, and haven't been able to spot my error...so my question is - what's really wrong? I'm using gcc 4.8.1.

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\stuff.o" "..\\src\\stuff.cpp" 
..\src\stuff.cpp: In constructor 'some_class<T, TBase>::some_class(const some_class<U,     UBase>&)':
..\src\stuff.cpp:87:10: error: default argument for template parameter for class     enclosing 'T t(U (*)())'
   T t(U());
      ^
..\src\stuff.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\src\stuff.cpp:104:16: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
  some_class<int> a;
            ^
..\src\stuff.cpp:82:7: error: provided for 'template<class T, class TBase> class   some_class'
 class some_class : public TBase{
   ^
..\src\stuff.cpp:104:19: error: invalid type in declaration before ';' token
  some_class<int> a;
```

Edit: Spot on answers, Cheers :-) Even if I still think it should compile... this compiles...

```
template <typename T>
struct some_other_class{
some_other_class(){}
    template <typename U>
    some_other_class(){
        T t(U());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
T t(U());
```

It is so-called ["most vexing parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It is function declaration which returns T, and takes nullary function which returns U as a parameter. Imagine:

```
typedef U nullary_function_return_U();
T t(nullary_function_return_U /*param_name*/)
{
    return T;
}
```

You can workaround it by adding parentheses:

```
T t( (U()) );
```

Or in C++11, you can use uniform initialization syntax:

```
T t{U{}};
```

---

> most vexing indeed.The error message is really terrible and regardless of the most vexing parse, it should really compile, shouldn't it?

I have tested on GCC 4.8.1 - Error, Clang 3.4 - OK, MSVC2010 - OK. I cut down it to smallest case which triggers error on [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fa616a7f18e2485):

```
template <typename = int>
struct Foo
{
    Foo()
    {
        int t(int()); // Error
    }
};

int main()
{
    int t(int()); // OK
    Foo<> a; // Error
}
```

This looks like GCC bug. I have made report to [GCC Bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58898).

---

**Edit**:

> Paolo Carlini 2014-07-07 14:11:14 UTC
>    This is already fixed mainline and 4.9.1. I'm adding the testcase and closing the bug.

Comment: most vexing indeed.The error message is really terrible and regardless of the most vexing parse, it should really compile, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Magnus see my edit - it looks like GCC bug. I opened ticket in  GCC Bugzilla.

Comment: Cheers, It's quite an obscure combination so I'm not surprised about the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to declare a function named `t`, taking a function returning `U` as argument, and returning `T`? When disambiguating the declaration to declare a variable `t` using, e.g.,

```
T t{U()};
```

it seems gcc is happy with the decaration.

Comment: I don't, it's indeed the most vexing parse, but if I did, what's the actual error?

Comment: @Magnus: probably something internal to gcc: clang happily compiles the original code (although with a warning about a function being declared).

Comment: I was suspecting something like that
btemplate <typename T>
struct some_other_class{
 some_other_class(){}
 template <typename U>
 some_other_class(){
  T t(U());
 }
};

Comment: oh, I can't have code segments here in the comments... anyway, I'm not sure what the g++ error messages are all about. If I'd got a warning about local function declaration or something like that, it would've been easy to figure out...

Comment: @Magnus: you can at least set text in monospace by enclosing it in backticks (shift-~ on a US keyboard)